# Correct way to check if any object is a SyntheticEvent?

Tags: reactjs

What is the best way to check if a given object of any kind is a [SyntheticEvent](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html)?

Currently, I'm peering into the internals:

```
if (obj.nativeEvent ) {
    // 100% sure...with this version of React
}
```

What is a more idiomatic (or at least future-proof) way of doing this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use such check: `if (!(event instanceof Event))`.

`event` (which is `SyntheticEvent`) will give `false` in this case and `event.nativeEvent` will give `true`.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. But what if I was not looking to differentiate between an event and a synthetic event, but actually to check if any object is a SyntheticEvent? Question edited for clarity

Comment: e.nativeEvent && e.nativeEvent instanceof Event will duck type your SyntheticEvent instance, AFAICT it's the only way to check effectively.

Answer (score 5):

I check if `obj.constructor.name === 'SyntheticEvent'`.

Comment: this causes issues if you're using tools that affect the name of functions in your production build. e.g. e.constructor.name for an synthetic event in my prod build is "W"